# Trying to use Selenium 2 with Python bindings, but I'm getting an import error

Tags: python, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I just installed Selenium 2 by doing `pip install selenium` and just copied some example tests to make sure that it's working:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.send_keys("selenium")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "Google" in driver.title
driver.close()
```

I saved that as `test.py` in a sub-folder in my Home folder on my Mac, but when ever I run `python test.py`, I get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ImportError: cannot import name webdriver
```

If I move that file into my Home directory, it works. If you couldn't tell, I'm just getting started with Selenium and programming. Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 62):

It sounds like you have some other module in your path named "selenium", and python is trying to import that one because it comes earlier in your python path. Did you name your file "selenium.py", for example?

To debug, import selenium with a simple `import selenium` then print the name of the file that was imported with `print selenium.__file__`

If you have a file named "selenium.py" which is not the proper selenium library, in addition to renaming or removing it, make sure you also delete "selenium.pyc", or python will continue to try to import from the .pyc file.

Comment: The output I got from that was: `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/__init__.pyc`

Does that look correct?

Comment: Yes, that looks correct. Is that after you moved it to your home directory or before? Make sure it's in the place where you get the import error, otherwise you're just proving what you already know -- that the version in your home directory works.

Comment: Thank you for this, helped me when I was doing testing in a file i (stupidly) named selenium.py ... :)

Comment: in my case I accidentally named my py file selenium.py

Answer (score 29):

Old question, but I did the same thing too. Named my file 'selenium.py' and it gave this very error message. Renamed the file to something else, but still got the same error. The problem was, that the selenium.pyc file had been created, since I ran the script from the terminal. Removed the .pyc file and it ran like a charm!

Comment: I had also to close the terminal and open a new one, so the changes took effect

Comment: +1 I found exactly this issue when I mistakenly named my file selenium.py - the resolution was to delete the selenium.pyc file as described

Comment: This needs more upvotes. Here I was fumbling around with my paths and environments for an hour, and all along it was because I named the file selenium.py

Answer (score 5):

Though the question seems to be inactive quite a long time, I had the same message/similar problem, and none of the answers above fit.

The site http://kevingann.blogspot.de/2012/11/troubleshooting-pydev-and-selenium.html gave the crucial hint.

Selenium occured twice, once in the system libs as egg, and the "installed" version in the external libs. Smashing the egg did the trick.

Hope this will help someone too

Comment: yep, that helped, had selenium folder in c:\Anaconda3\selenium with just this contents in it, everything was working, but Pycharm always scream out yellow warnings, for example, that 'cannot find reference PhantomJS in imported module selenium.webdriver':

And looks like it shadowed this one:

c:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\

After deleting c:\Anaconda3\selenium there is no warnings in pycharm

Answer (score 3):

the error `ImportError: cannot import name webdriver or no module selenium2library` was resolved by placing selenium folder directly under `Lib` instead of `site_packages`

Answer (score 0):

Error in Pycharm "Cannot find reference 'Chrome' in 'imported module selenium.webdriver'" got resolved after copying selenium dir from site-packages to lib.
Can be verified as stated above

```
import selenium
print (selenium.__file__)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Sethe project interpreter as actual python.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Knb1C.png)

I am able to run successfully the code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

opts = Options()
prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}  
opts.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)


# enter complete path of chrome driver as argument to below line of code 
browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\BLR153\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe')
# browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get('http://www.google.com')

time.sleep(10)

browser.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just name your pytnon file NOT selenium.py !!!
It is not looking for webdriver in selenium, but in your file, where you are trying to connect it

Comment: In Bryan's answer: `If you have a file named "selenium.py" which is not the proper selenium library, in addition to renaming or removing it, make sure you also delete "selenium.pyc", or python will continue to try to import from the .pyc file.`

Answer (score -3):

1. Make sure that you have **only one python** version installed
2. Install pip
3. Install selenium using pip
     *pip install selenium*
4. Run the script

Hope that helps.