# selenium 2- python- cannot import webdriver even though selenium is up to date

Tags: python, selenium

Im trying to use selenium in python 2.7 and when trying to import webdriver it gives me the error "ImportError: cannot import name webdriver" Ive had a search around and people seem to say updating it should sort the problem which i have tried using "pip install -U Selenium" which responds saying it is already upto date.

This is the full reply i get when running my script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py",
    line   326, in RunScript
        exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__
    File "C:\Python27\selenium.py", line 1, in <module>
        from selenium import webdriver
    File "C:\Python27\selenium.py", line 1, in <module>
        from selenium import webdriver
ImportError: cannot import name webdriver
```

Comment: Check this out and see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426851/trying-to-use-selenium-2-with-python-bindings-but-im-getting-an-import-error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think looking at what you have (although python is pretty far down my known languages list) that the problem is related to the wrong selenium being imported. Have a look at:

[Trying to use Selenium 2 with Python bindings, but I'm getting an import error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426851/trying-to-use-selenium-2-with-python-bindings-but-im-getting-an-import-error)

Comment: realized that i stupidly called my script selenium.py which seems to of been causing the error

Comment: I bet you are far from the first person to do that!