# ImportError: cannot import name webdriver

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I am implementing selenium and i have already included "from selenium import webdriver" but still getting this error

> "ImportError: cannot import name webdriver"

Any idea how to resolve this error?

Comment: isn't this a duplicate of your question?[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426851/trying-to-use-selenium-2-with-python-bindings-but-im-getting-an-import-error)

Comment: yea i am getting same error.

Comment: maybe you name your file 'selenium.py' or the problem was, that the selenium.pyc file had been created when the script was ran from you terminal. try removing the .pyc

Comment: read from the link i have shared. i think all was well explained there

Answer (score 0):

Cross check your language binding, check with older versions