# ImportError: Cannot import name 'webdriver''

Tags: python, selenium

Here is my code.

```
import sys
print (sys.path)

from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import BY 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

usernameStr = 'email'
passwordStr = 'password'

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://website.com')



username = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="did-ui"]/div/div/section/section/form/section/div[1]/div/label/span[2]/input')
username.send_keys(usernameStr)
password = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="did-ui"]/div/div/section/section/form/section/div[2]/div/label/span[2]/input')
password.send_keys(passwordStr)
nextButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="did-ui"]/div/div/section/section/form/section/div[3]/button[1]')
nextButton.click()
```

When I run it I get this error,

```
['/Users/austinjohnson/Desktop/streakscraper', '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6', '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/austinjohnson/Desktop/streakscraper/login.py", line 6, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver 
ImportError: cannot import name 'webdriver'
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['/usr/local/bin/python3', '-u', '/Users/austinjohnson/Desktop/streakscraper/login.py']]
[dir: /Users/austinjohnson/Desktop/streakscraper]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

I can't figure out why I keep getting an error. I've tried to change the path to give it access, but I still get an error. Maybe I did something wrong, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I don't know if this was a complete noob move or not, but I solved my problem. I linked the PYTHONPATH from the directory that it was stored in to the directory that my project was stored in. Problem solved.

> Steps:
>   1. cd to home directory = /Users/username
>
> 2. nano .bash_profile
> 3. Paste

```
xport PATH=/usr/local/share/python:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python:$PYTHONPATH
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6.1/lib/python3/site-packages/
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

> 4. cd to directory the program you are trying to run is actually in
> 5. Repeat step 2
> 6. Repeat step 3.

Feel free to laugh, cry, scream - I'm doing all three.

Answer (score 8):

Do you possibly have a file called `selenium.py`? Take a look at this post, it may be able to help you. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426851/trying-to-use-selenium-2-with-python-bindings-but-im-getting-an-import-error)