# ImportError: cannot import name 'webdriver' - no Selenium.py file

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am getting an issue in my code with webdriver not being imported. I am using selenium and have already made sure the path is correct. I do not have any file named 'selenium.py' or 'selenium.pyc' that is causing this issue. If it helps, I am using windows, not a mac.

When importing selenium and checking the file it was imported with I get the following input/output:

input:

```
import selenium
print(selenium.__file__)
```

output:

```
runfile('D:/Users/admin/temp2.py', wdir='D:/Users/admin')
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\selenium\__init__.py
```

My code is as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


dir_name = 'D:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\New folder'
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"download.default_directory" : 'D:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\New 
folder'}
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
chromedriver ='D:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, 
chrome_options=chromeOptions)
```

The Output:

```
runfile('D:/Users/admin/.spyder-py3/temp.py', 
wdir='D:/Users/admin/.spyder-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-3-c032ba6dd2a9>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('D:/Users/admin/.spyder-py3/temp.py', 
wdir='D:/Users/admin/.spyder-py3')

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "D:/Users/admin/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 2, in <module>
from selenium import webdriver

ImportError: cannot import name 'webdriver'
```

A similar question described the python path, but I don't believe that is the issue here either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: Cannot import name 'webdriver''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43529497/importerror-cannot-import-name-webdriver)

Comment: Nope, I checked that post already, it did not fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

So eventually I realized that it can't find the webdriver because someone actually (hopefully accidentally) deleted it off the computer.

Just reinstalled Selenium altogether and restarted the computer. Working fine now!