# How to import sucsesfully selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, bots, python-import, importerror

I have just started to try to learn to use selenium. When i try to import from selenium the module webdriver, like this:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
```

Only this but the shell say

```
    ImportError: cannot import name 'webdriver' from partially initialized module 'selenium' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

What should i do? Thanks

Comment: Hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/7431021/3295856

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you named your file selenium.py

If yes:
then change the name please.

Comment: Oh jeez I would never guess that it is prohibited somehow! Thanks!